# Concatenating strings in Visual Studio C++ 6.0 in a loop

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

Can you help me optimize this block of code in C++ for Visual Studio C++ 6.0:

```
char output[10000] = "";
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    char row[150];
    _snprintf(row, 149, "…", …);
    row[149] = '\0';
    strcat(output, row);
}
return _snprintf(buffer, size-1, "%s\r\nend\r\n", output);
```

What I need is that I do not specify size of output[] but increase it dynamically. The same maybe true for row[]. Sorry I'm novice in C++.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You've tagged this as C++ but it looks like C ?

Comment: Visual C++ 6.0?  You know that's 14 years old, right?

Comment: Visual Studio C++ 6.0 is not compliant with the first C++ standard (1998) and had compatibility problems with trying to use the C++ standard library. The only reason to use it today is maintenance on legacy software. Switch to a compiler that supports standard C++ and the posted answers will solve your problem of dynamically increasing string sizes.

Comment: @AviBerger: The compiler may be old, but its library still contains `std::string` and `std::stringstream`, which is what's needed here. C++ had a "standard" long before ISO got their hands on it.

Comment: Yes, I know it's old. But it's existing project and I just need to update it. I already tried to build it with newer versions of Visual Studio but it doesn't work. It's a plugin for other application.

Answer (score 6):

In C++, you ought to use `std::string` for strings instead of `char` arrays, and `std::stringstream` and its cousins `std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream` instead of `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` for formatting in string buffers. Here’s the basis of a C++ solution:

```
std::ostringstream result;
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
    result << "...\n";
}
result << "end\n";
return result.str();
```

The `std::string` class handles all of the details of managing memory, and `std::stringstream` uses `std::string` internally.

Answer (score 3):

`std::stringstream` coupled with `operator <<` works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of C++ containers given as answers are not as optimized as you can get.  There has been no memory reserved to begin with, and the results do not copy into the `buffer` as in your supplied code.

You can still do better like this:

```
char suffix[] = "\r\nend\r\n";
int suffix_len = strlen(suffix);
char *buf_end = buffer + size - suffix_len - 1;
char *buf_begin = buffer;

for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    int nchars = _snprintf(buf_begin, buf_end-buf_begin, "…", …);
    if( nchars >= 0 ) {
        buf_begin += nchars;
    } else {
        // You may want to set an overflow flag here.
        buf_begin = buf_end;
        break;
    }
}

// There will always be enough room in the buffer to store the suffix, so 
// this will null-terminate even if the above loop overflowed the buffer.
_sprintf(buf_begin, "%s", suffix);
```

I've modified this to write directly into `buffer` instead of `output`.  It utilizes the fact that the `_sprintf` family returns the number of characters written (or negative if max chars written).  To me, this is the preferable way to concatenate data into a buffer, even in C++.

Comment: Oh, I handled overflow differently from your solution.  Is that important?  *ie* clipping at 149 characters.  Or is that much more than you ever need?  If you need to clip long rows, I can modify to suit.  You don't do any bounds checking on your 10000-byte buffer either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MFC`, it is very easy using the `CString` class:

```
// loop count
int nCount = 100;
CString strOutput, strOne;
for (int i=0 ; i<nCount ; i++)
{   // format one line
    strOne.Format(_T("..."), ...);
    // accumulate the result
    strOutput += strOne;
}
return strOutput;
```